# sum in whereRaw in Laravel how can I solve that?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hi i'm working on a query with eloquent to get the id of all invoices that have more than 100 products, this is what i'm trying:

```
 $products = Product::whereRaw('sum(quantity) >= 100')->pluck('invoice_id');
```

I get this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select `invoice_id` from `products` where sum(quantity) >= 100)
```

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `having` statement in `whereHas` for this.

```
$invoices = Invoice::whereHas('products', fn($q) => $q->select('quantity')->havingRaw('SUM(quantity) >= 100')->groupBy('quantity'))->get();
```

Or, without arrow function (I know it's scary some people :)):

```
$invoices = Invoice::whereHas('products', function($query){
    return $query->select('quantity')
        ->havingRaw('SUM(quantity) >= 100')
        ->groupBy('quantity');
})->get();
```

Select and groupBy added to query to avoid strict mode errors.